# Minimum Path without Bomb

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

A 2-D matrix of size N x M is given. Data in each cell represents the time to cross the cell. Some blocks are containing negative values denoting a bomb. We need to find minimum time of reaching to [n-1 , m-1] from [0 , 0] without passing through any bomb.

- Do i need to do BFS here or Dijkstra here? If I do BFS, how does it determine shortest time / minimum time?
- If I do Dijkstra, how do I get a path from [0, 0] cell to [n-1, m-1].

Example Matrix:

```
                        {0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1},
                        {4, 0, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, 11, -1},
                        {-1, 8, 0, 7, -1, 4, -1, -1, 2},
                        {-1, -1, 7, 0, 9, 14, -1, -1, -1},
                        {-1, -1, -1, 9, 0, 10, -1, -1, 1},
                        {-1, -1, 4, -1, 10, 0, 2, -1, -1},
                        {-1, -1, -1, 14, -1, 2, 0, 1, 6},
                        {8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 7},
                        {-1, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 6, 7, 0}
```

Comment: BFS will find you the path with the smallest number of cells visited, but that can be very different from the shortest total traversal time.

Comment: Is this matrix an adjacency matrix, or does it represent a grid with implied connections between adjacent cells?

Comment: It's just a matrix whose values represent cost of that cell.

Comment: To be clear, the cost is associated with *entering* the cell?

Comment: It's a matrix whose values represent cost to pass that cell. So the source could be any [i, j] instead of [0, 0] and the destination could be any [i, j] instead of [n-1, m-1]. In generally speaking, I need the shortest path in terms of cost ( here time ), from any source [a, b] to destination [c, d].

Comment: Say I'm in a cell with cost 7.  There's a cell next to me with cost 5.  Does it cost me 5 to enter that neighboring cell? Or 7?

Comment: It costs 5. Whatever the cell value is that is the cost to pass / enter that cell. You need to find out the minimum path from any source point (a, b) to destination (c, d) such that total cost along the path is minimum.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel  please suggest what to do.

Comment: @therainmaker's answer is a good guide.  When translating the matrix to a graph, just don't even generate vertices for bomb cells and you don't have to worry about special-casing them during the actual execution of Dijkstra's.

Answer (score 2):

If the 2D matrix is made as a graph, then the cost of traversal of each edge is same. In that case, Djikstra's is equivalent to a BFS. Since each cell has a different cost of crossing, Djikstra isn't equivalent to BFS here. BFS will determine minimum number of cells needed to cross, but not the minimum time. So the requirement is of Djiksta's. This answers your first query.

I'm assuming you know how to implement Djikstra's. The issue which you are facing is how to implement it on this question. For that, you need to represent a 2D matrix as a graph. The main question which arises is how to capture the relationship of node values in a graph. This may arise because you are used to thinking of weights on edges, but not on vertices. However, you can simply reduce problem to Djikstra's by making it a directed graph, where the cost of edge of from `[i][k]` to `[j][k]` as the value of `[j][k]`, and the cost of edge in the backwards direction as value of `[i][k]`. To incorporate the concept of a bomb, simply don't generate vertices for those cells. After this, applying Djikstra's should be straightforward.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. I need the minimum cost path say shortest ( time ) path from (0, 0) to (n-1, m-1). Cost of the path is to be considered. I am not considering length of the pat at all.

Comment: If it's a graph, I wouldn't have asked the question. It's a matrix whose values represent cost to pass that cell. So the source could be any [i, j] instead of [0, 0] and the destination could be any [i, j] instead of [n-1, m-1].

Comment: @kosre I had misread the question. I have edited the answer now. Let me know if it answers your queries

Comment: I am not confused about the vertex weights. I am confused about the source and destination. If say the source is [1, 2] and destination is [5, 4], then between which points I need to apply Dijkstra's approach? If I start from [1, 1], how to apply Dijkstra so that I stop at say [5, 4].

Comment: @kosre For that, I suggest you look at the implementation of Djikstra's, as this is an issue independent of the scenario painted here. How do you determine the stopping criteria when Djikstra runs in any graph? When it has visited all vertices. It's the same thing here.

Comment: For source [1, 1] & destination [5, 4] - what is the source vertex and what is the destination vertex in case I want to implement the Dijkstra directly?

Comment: @kosre after you convert your 2D matrix into a graph, the source will be the node corresponding to [1,1] and destination will be node corresponding to [5,4]. This however seems too trivial. So either I have misunderstood what you have said, or you aren't able to express yourself properly.

Comment: The problem is in usual Dijkstra implementation if I need to find out shortest path say from vertex - 1 to vertex - 5, the path can go through any other vertex and Dijkstra stops when it visits the vertex  - 5. But here specifically I need the shortest path between between any (a, b) and (c, d). So I am not able to apply Dijkstra directly. In usual BFS I can achieve this but there is no guarantee of shortest COST path. So the problem is mapping between the given matrix and expected graph. The question requires exact shortest path where source and destinations are matrix coordinates not vrtxs.

Comment: @kosre From what I understand, the issue is in mapping this matrix to a graph. Right?

Comment: Yes that is the issue.

Comment: @kosre That is what I have tried to address in the answer. You define every cell as a vertex. Which vertices will have an edge, and the cost of the edge, is explained in the answer. After this you'll have a graph. Now you can apply Djikstra's on the graph. On which part of this, do you have an issue?

Comment: @therainmaker - to avoid overflow, just don't generate vertices for bomb cells at all.

Comment: @therainmaker - okay got it. Thanks. Let me try now.

Answer (score 1):

Create a graph from the 2D grid (each location is a node, edges to the locations above, below, to the right and the left. Bomb locations just don't go in), but after you've done the initial creation, use step 2:

Let's say node `(x,y)` has value 8, and  it is accessible from four nodes (in the grid: one above, to the right, the left and below). You transform the node into 4 nodes - one adjacent to each neighbor and these four nodes are connected between themselves (clique) with edges of value 8.

Once this is done on all the graph, run Dijkstra...